How to use jax.custom_vjp with functions that take non-JAX types (e.g., SymPy expressions) as inputs?
I'm trying to use JAX's custom_vjp to define custom gradient computations for a function that takes a SymPy expression as an input. However, I'm encountering errors because JAX doesn't support non-JAX types as inputs for functions that are transformed (e.g., with grad, jit, or custom_vjp). I am recently modifying code in ScQubits to add a new jax backend to improve the efficiency, and then I meet some problem with jax and sympy.
Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do:
import jax
import sympy as sm

# Define symbols and expression
x, y, z = sm.symbols('x y z')
expr = x**2 + 2*y + z

# Attempt to iterate over expr (this will cause an error)
try:
    for term in expr:
        print(term)
except TypeError as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

# Define a function that takes a SymPy expression and a value
def sympy_function(expr, x_value):
    x = sm.Symbol('x')
    result = expr.subs(x, x_value)
    return float(result)

# Attempt to apply custom_vjp
sympy_function = jax.custom_vjp(sympy_function)

def sympy_function_fwd(expr, x_value):
    y = sympy_function(expr, x_value)
    return y, (expr, x_value)

def sympy_function_bwd(residual, grad_y):
    expr, x_value = residual
    x = sm.Symbol('x')
    derivative_expr = sm.diff(expr, x)
    grad_x_value = float(derivative_expr.subs(x, x_value))
    grad_expr = None
    return grad_expr, grad_y * grad_x_value

sympy_function.defvjp(sympy_function_fwd, sympy_function_bwd)

# Test the function
x = sm.Symbol('x')
expr = x**2 + 3*x + 2
x_value = 1.0

# This will raise an error
y = sympy_function(expr, x_value)

When I run this code, I get an error like:
TypeError: Value x**2 + 3*x + 2 with type <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> is not a valid JAX type

How can I use jax.custom_vjp with functions that take non-JAX types like SymPy expressions as inputs? Is there a way to work around this limitation, or to make JAX accept such functions?

There is no way to do what you're trying to do: JAX transformations like custom_jvp can only differentiate with respect to JAX-compatible values like Arrays and pytrees. Non-JAX values can only be used as nondiff_argnums within the custom_vjp; in this case, the only arguments to your function are non-differentiable arguments. As a result the custom_vjp is unnecessary, because your function is not differentiable within JAX's autodiff framework.

Do you just want a faster way to evaluate the derivatives of your symbolic expressions? It sounds like your motivation in trying to create a custom_vjp is to enable JAX to differentiate through a sympy expression.
sympy2jax solves this problem for you. It creates an equinox module from your sympy expression that JAX can differentiate through.
Here is a minimal example that shows how you can go about this:
import jax
import sympy
import sympy2jax

x_sym = sympy.symbols("x_sym")
cosx = 1.0 * sympy.cos(x_sym)
mod = sympy2jax.SymbolicModule(cosx) 

def f(x, mod):
    out = mod(x_sym=x)
    return out
jax.grad(f)(1.0, mod)  # Will work

You may also want to check out equinox, which will allow you to use filtered versions of jit and grad that do not come with the limitation that all function inputs are PyTrees of arrays.
